# Integral Homology of GIT Quotients

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

Is there any example of GIT quotients of linear actions on a Euclidean space ${\mathbb C}^n$ that satisfy the following conditions?

1. The quotient is compact and smooth.
2. The homology of the quotient has nontrivial torsion part.